# Copying an image file to an empty folder in using WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

After going through all the related stuff to copying files i am unable to find an answer to my 
problem of an exception occurring while i was trying to copy a file to an empty folder in WPF application. Here is the code snippet.

```
public static void Copy()
{
    string _finalPath;
    foreach (var name in files) // name is the filename extracted using GetFileName in a list of strings
    {
        _finalPath = filePath; //it is the destination folder path e.g,C:\Users\Neha\Pictures\11-03-2014
        if(System.IO.Directory.Exists(_finalPath))
        {
            _finalPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(_finalPath,name);
            System.IO.File.Copy(name, _finalPath , true);
        }
    }
}
```

While debugging exception is occuring at file.copy() statement which says

> "FileNotFoundException was unhandled" could not find file

i already know about the combining path and other aspects of copy but i dont know why this exception is being raised.
I am a noob to WPF please help.........

Comment: if  System.IO.File.Copy raise FileNotFoundException, it's quite sure that source file is not at his correct path. Try to put a break point File.Copy(name, ...) before it raises exception.

Comment: is there a problem with your combine have u tried with System.IO.File.Copy(name, _finalPath +"\" +name , true); ?

Comment: Where do you get the `files` list from? You should check for the existence of `name` using `System.IO.File.Exists(name)`.

Comment: Try to put **@** symbol. `_finalPath = @filePath;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code:

```
    public static void Copy()
    {
        string _finalPath;
        var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\"); // Here replace C:\ with your directory path.
        foreach (var file in files)             
        {
            var filename = file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1); // Get the filename from absolute path
            _finalPath = filePath; //it is the destination folder path e.g,C:\Users\Neha\Pictures\11-03-2014
            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(_finalPath))
            {
                _finalPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(_finalPath, filename);
                System.IO.File.Copy(file, _finalPath, true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `GetFileName ()`
only returns the actual name of the file (drops the path) what you want is a full path to the file. So you getting an exception because the 'name' does not exist on your drive (path is unknown)

Answer (score 0):

You're variable, `name`, is most likely just the file name (i.e. something.jpg). When you use the `File.Copy(...)` method, if you do not supply an absolute path the method assumes a path relative to the executable.

Basically, if you are running your app in, for example, C:\Projects\SomeProject\bin\Debug\SomeProject.exe, then it is assuming your file is C:\Projects\SomeProject\bin\Debug\something.jpg.

Comment: so you are trying to say that i should use combine method on absolute paths of both source file and destination folder???

Comment: No, I can't really say what the solution is because there isn't enough information. The problem you have is that files contains just file names, not full paths. Wherever you grab `files` from, they should be returned as `FileInfo` objects or absolute path strings, unless relative path is what you really do need (which it isn't).

Comment: earlier i was doing it with complete path of files but same problem was there then i read on stackoverflow itself that you should combine filename to folder path......